# Navigate to my action/controller/id from jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to navigate to my action/controller/id not from an ActionLink but from jQuery. Here is what I do:

```
    $('.search-results tr').click(function () {
        var IdSuite = $(this).data('idsuite');
        var IdAffaire = $(this).data('idaffaire');            
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Detail","Suite", new { IdAffaire = "idAffaire", IdSuite = "idSuite" }))';
        url = url.replace("idSuite", IdSuite);
        url = url.replace("idAffaire", IdAffaire);
        window.location = url;
    });
```

I know it works but I would like to know if this is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this.
If you want the user to be able to go back to the previous page after redirecting him, then using `window.location = url` is fine, otherwise you can use `window.location.replace = url`

Comment: I don't want to go back to the previous page. I want to go to navigate to a specific controller/action/id (ASP.NET MVC) and thus I need to construc the URL.

Comment: My comment was about the difference between window.location and window.location.replace. Let's say that you correctly redirect the user to /Suite/Detail/...  but then the user wants to go back to the previous page: "window.location = url" allows the user to press the Back button and to navigate back to the previous page as expected, "window.location.replace = url" doesn't because it's replacing the Url of the current page.